# Summing matrices in matlab (with a twist)

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I have a matrix `H`, which for arguments sake is of size 6-by-6.

I need to sum three things, first I need `h_ii`, then I need to sum all the other elements which contain element `i`, apart from `h_ii`. Then I need all the other that do not contain `j`.

To visualise this, have created the following diagram,

[image]

So from the diagram,

For each diagonal of the matrix, `h11`, `h22`, ... , `h66`.

I need to sum the orange (cells that contain all the `ij` cells), and then the yellow, (the cells that do not contain `i`, the `jj` cells).

I have tried to sum the individual columns and rows but this becomes very messy.

Ideally, I need to give the matrix, and it produces `h11 = X`, `h11_orange = Y`, and `h11_yellow = Z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```matlab
h=magic(6);
out = zeros(size(h,1),size(h,2),3);  % Initialise output
out(:,:,1) = h;  % Copy the green

for ii = 1:size(h,1)
    for jj = 1:size(h,2)
        % out(ii,jj,1) = h(ii,jj);  % Green bit
        % For orange, sum the row and column. Note the .' transpose,
        % otherwise implicit broadcasting on the plus will create a matrix.
        % Finally remove the green cell twice,
        % as you added it in both row and column
        out(ii,jj,2) = sum(h(ii,:)+h(:,jj).') - h(ii,jj)*2;
        % Sum everything for yellow, and subtract the orange and green
        out(ii,jj,3) = sum(h,'all') - out(ii,jj,2) - h(ii,jj)
    end
end
```

This will make a 3D output matrix, i.e. it's of the same size as the input matrix with 3 pages for your green, orange and yellow parts. See the comments in the code for what does what.

Thanks [flawr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2913106/flawr) for [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154902/summing-matrices-in-matlab-with-a-twist/64155294?noredirect=1#comment113449696_64155294) on improving speed on the yellow summation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this vectorized version:

```
green = diag(H);
orange = sum(H,1).' + sum(H,2) - 2* green;
yellow = sum(H(:)) - orange - green;
```

Comment: I think you need `-2*green` in `orange`, otherwise it would be too `brown` :P

Comment: I think you can easily extend this for off-diagonal elements; `green=H; orange = sum(H,1)+sum(H,2)-2*green`, by using implicit broadcasting on the plus sign. A better and faster solution than mine, this should be accepted IMO.

Comment: I think  @flawr 's comments should be accepted. Because of providing  good suggestions and correcting my mistake. It is written in the language of humor that I think we need such language specially during the pandemic!